# Empty string concatenation in this exercise

Tags: javascript

We have the exercise

Determine and print the smallest and largest values contained in 99-element floatingpoint array `w`.

The solution is :

```
var highestNumber = w[ 0 ];
var lowestNumber = w[ 0 ];

for ( var i = 1; i < 99; i++ )
{
    if ( w[ i ] > highestNumber )
        highestNumber = w[ i ];
    if ( w[ i ] < lowestNumber )
        lowestNumber = w[ i ];
}
document.writeln( highestNumber + " " + lowestNumber );
```

What is the purpose of the string concatenation `" "` in here?

Comment: one space between two values..

Comment: `" "` to provide some space between the 2 numbers

Comment: Why didn't you try removing it to see what would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `" "` creates an empty space in the string so it will look like this:

```
document.writeln( X + " " + Y );

X Y
```

rather than

```
document.writeln( X + Y );

XY
```

Answer (score 0):

The `" "` will provide space between the given highest and lowest value.Like this `99 85` otherwise it will show like this `9985`

```
highestNumber = 99;

lowestNumber = 85;
```

**Example :**

```
document.writeln( highestNumber + " " + lowestNumber );
```

**OutPut :**

```
99 85
```